# Embedding pgfplots' plot3 into a tikz-3dplot

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to embed a 2D Gaussian into a tikz-3dplot, but I'm having problems transforming the coordinate systems. As a simplified example, I'm plotting a plane in pgflots' `\addplot3` and I'm embedding the plot into a tikz-3dplot:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{155}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal}{4}{%
  %\pgfmathparse{x+y}
  \pgfmathparse{1}
}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

% receiver
\pgfmathsetmacro\minx{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\maxx{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\miny{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\maxy{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextx{\minx+1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\nexty{\miny+1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\z{0}
\foreach \x in {\minx,\nextx,...,\maxx}
{
  \foreach \y in {\miny,\nexty,...,\maxy}
  {
    \draw[gray] (\x,\miny,\z) -- (\x,\maxy,\z);
    \draw[gray] (\minx,\y,\z) -- (\maxx, \y,\z);
  }
}


\draw[->, very thick,red] (-2,-3,0) -- (1,-3,0) node [above] {$x$};
\draw[->, very thick,blue] (-2,-3,0) -- (-2,0,0) node [above] {$y$};
\draw[->, very thick,green] (-2,-3,0) -- (-2,-3,3) node [above] {$z$};
\begin{axis}[
  anchor={south east}, view={155}{20}, samples=10, xlabel={X}, ylabel={Y},
  zlabel={Z}, width=10cm,height=10cm,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,zmin=-5,zmax=5
]
  \addplot3[surf]{normal(0,0,0.2,0.2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: A tikz-3dplot with a pgfplots plot3]

This seems to be working, although I'm not sure if the axes are actually aligned. However, I couldn't generalize the transformation; whenever I change `\tdplotsetmaincoords`, I need to find a suitable transformation by trial-and-error, often it fails completely.

What is the general transformation from tikz-3dplot coordinates to pgfplots coordinates? Is there a way to do this without computing the transformation explicitly?

My guess so far is that for `tdplotsetmaincoords{x}{y}`, I need to set `view={y}{?}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its default config, `pgfplots` has lots of freedom to scale the image as it seems fit: the default is `scale mode=auto` which boils down to `scale mode=stretch to fill`. As the name suggests, `stretch to fill` is likely to distort the angles between unit vectors, although the image is still correct internally.

This is also true for your axis: `pgfplots` merely needs to respect `width` and `heigth` as constraints and will *rescale* unit vectors at will. In order to align them with the (external) coordinate system, you will need to use `scale mode=scale uniformly` or you will need to resort to explicitly set axis vectors (options `x=(exx,exy)` and its variants). Please refer to the pgfplots reference manual section "Scaling Options" and the mentioned choices.

As you already stated in your question, you also need to determine how to map `\tdplotsetmaincoords` to the angles accepted by `view`. My answer currently does not cover this piece of information (due to a lack of time to think through it). Without having thought through the details, my guess is that you will need some combination of "exchange arguments and/or add some multiple of 90 to some of the angles".